# how to program this in basic without goto, but also without low computing time

Tags: goto, basic

nam() is a string Array, and should not be compared too often, takes long. vnr() is an integer Array, and normally is the only thing that is compared. this means vnr(i2) = vnr(i3) is a rare event. how to make it that there are even not two integer comparisons (the second // line is optional, because already compared in first line).

```
    if vnr(i2) >= vnr(i3) Then
      if vnr(i2) = vnr(i3) Then
        If nam(i2) > nam(i3) Then
          GoTo tausche
        End If
      Else
    tausche:
        i4 = vnr(i2)
        s8 = nam(i2)
        vnr(i2) = vnr(i3)
        nam(i2) = nam(i3)
        vnr(i3) = i4
        nam(i3) = s8
      End If
    End If
```

Answer (score 0):

The normal thing to do would be to (a) use a subroutine to avoid the goto, and (b) either reverse the logic or remove the extra condition so that the more common event comes first. Reversing the logic would produce something like:

```
if vnr(i2) < vnr(i3) then
    gosub tausche
else if vnr(i2) = vnr(i3) then
    if nam(i2) > nam(i3) then
        gosub tausche
    end if
end if

sub tausche
    i4 = vnr(i2)
    s8 = nam(i2)
    vnr(i2) = vnr(i3)
    nam(i2) = nam(i3)
    vnr(i3) = i4
    nam(i3) = s8
end sub
```

Removing the extra condition would produce something like:

```
if vnr(i2) > vnr(i3) then
    rem do nothing
else if vnr(i2) < vnr(i3) then
    gosub tasuche
else if nam(i2) > nam(i3) then
    gosub tausche
end if

sub tausche
    i4 = vnr(i2)
    s8 = nam(i2)
    vnr(i2) = vnr(i3)
    nam(i2) = nam(i3)
    vnr(i3) = i4
    nam(i3) = s8
end sub
```

To remove the double-check, instead of checking the combined condition of `vnr(i2) >= vnr(i3)`, separate out the greater than and the equal to.

In the second example, the first check checks that `vnr(i2) > vnr(i3)` and the second if they’re less than, so that we know that by the time the third comes around, they are equal, and we can simply leave that condition out and go straight to comparing the strings.

To remove the goto, use a subroutine. Depending on your implementation of BASIC, you may need a return at the end of the subroutine, of course.